# How to incluse a csv file within WCF service on Azure

Tags: c#, wcf, azure

I have a very WCF service and i need to include a small csv file within,

so here is what i already tried:

- I added the csv file as existing item
- I set 'copy to output directory' = 'copy always'

Now lets say i wanna access that file from within the WCF service, how do i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here it is:

```
  var filepath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/simple.csv");
```